# VS Code opens new browser everytime a change is made in Python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, bokeh

I am building a Bokeh app in **VS code** and whenever I hit Run (green arrow on top right), the changes open up to a new browser. I thought this would be easy to achieve but I am struggling to find a way where the same browser can just be refreshed whenever a change is made, instead of having a new browser opened up every time I hit run, for example

[image]

Is there a similar approach to **Live Server** used for html file for this? The code for my bokeh app is as below if it helps

```
from random import random

from bokeh.layouts import column, row, widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlBu3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, save
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CategoricalColorMapper, Legend, PrintfTickFormatter, CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.models.widgets import (Select)
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div


### Read in the data
df = pd.read_excel('RS data.xlsx')

### Set up Figure
p = figure(x_range=(0, 20), y_range=(0, 10), plot_height=400, plot_width=800)
p.add_layout(Legend(), 'right')
p.toolbar_location = None


df['Unique Story Count'] = df.groupby(['Person','Sprint'])['Story Id'].transform('nunique')

### Convert data into a bokeh data type
df1 = df[['Person', 'Sprint', 'Unique Story Count']]
df1['Person'].unique()
df1 = df1[df1['Person'] == 'Analyst 1'].drop_duplicates()
source1 = ColumnDataSource(df1)

x='Sprint'
y='Unique Story Count'

p1 = p.line(
    x=x, y=y, 
    color='#d96ad5', line_color='#d96ad5', 
    line_width=2, line_alpha=1, source=source1
)

p2 = p.circle(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    #legend_label='',
    size=6,
    fill_alpha=1,
    # color={'field': 'Submission', 'transform': mapper},
    source=source1
)

p.xaxis.ticker = list(range(0, 21))
p.xgrid.ticker = list(range(0, 21))

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Sprint'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Story Count'

## tooltip for point
p.add_tools(HoverTool(
    renderers=[p2],
    tooltips=[
        ('Spri Num', '@Sprint'),
        ('Story Count', '@{Unique Story Count}')
    ],
    mode='mouse')
)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `show()` opens the HTML file in the browser if `output_file()` has been called. This is stated inside the [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=show#bokeh-io-showing) as well.

You should use `save()` instead of `show()`, you can check the docs for `save()` over [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=save#bokeh.io.save). If you have live server opened on that HTML file you should be able to see the changes reflected on the HTML page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works! I replaced ```show(p)``` with ```save(p)``` and hit Run. I then opened the html file with Live Server. When I made changes in the Python script I needed to save and run it again to see the change in the same browser!

Comment: Great to hear :)

Comment: @MinhChau Could you please accept my answer as the answer to your question?

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot to!